# Firma de ensamblados en .NET

Tags: vb.net, .net

Mi solución en Visual Studio 2017 no compila correctamente. Devuelve el siguiente error:

> Error  BC41997 Referenced assembly 'xxx.XXX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have a strong name.   xxx.XXX Rutavbc 1   Active

Si tengo referencias a unas dll de terceros, ¿cómo las firmo?

¿Existe alguna forma de que no aparezca ese error ?

Comment: Quizás esto te pueda ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331520/how-to-fix-referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posiblemente te sirva el enlace siguiente:

https://github.com/brutaldev/StrongNameSigner

Después de descargarlo como zip en la carpeta de extracción **..\StrongNameSigner-master\src** se ubica la solución llamada **Brutal.Dev.StrongNameSigner.sln**, al abrirla es necesario establecer como proyecto de inicio **Brutal.Dev.StrongNameSigner.UI**

Al ejecutar el proyecto aparecerá una interfaz como la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El campo **Key File** puede estar vacío (o puedes adjuntar un *.pfx), en el campo **Password** establece una contraseña para firmar tu librería (o la contraseña de tu archivo *.pfx), en el campo **Output** se indica el directorio de salida de la(s) dll(s) y con el botón **+** se puede(n) agregar.

El paso final es dar clic sobre el botón Sign Assemblies y los ensamblados del directorio de salida estarán firmados. Para comprobarlo se puede ejecutar la siguiente línea en **PowerShell (no cmd)**:

```
([system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile("Directorio_salida\Ensamblado.dll")).FullName
```

Y como resultado obtendrás su información:

```
Ensamblado, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e0b51f6a207a4d33
```

Comment: muchas gracias me ayudo